# RESTful Web service Testing error in Netbeans 6.9 with Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, netbeans

Hi I have created a RESTful web service in netbeans 6.9 with mysql. I followed this tutorial from netbeans: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

But when I am trying to test the service I am getting the following error in browser. Can anyone please help how to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception     [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600):  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
Error Code: 0

root cause 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
Error Code: 0

root cause 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
Error Code: 0

root cause 
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem.
Can you please see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936746/mysql-and-glassfish-error-in-allocating-a-connection
Since I'm using mysql on wamp, I have given the following in Admin properties:
Path/URL to admin tool: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
Path to start command: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysqld.exe
Path to stop command: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysqld.exe
Arguments: -u root stop

It still does not seem to work. Can you please provide anymore pointers @meraz?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your response Ji. And no, I didn't have any space in the column. The issue is with the Admin Properties for the mySQL. I had to put the Path to start server, path to stop server etc in the Admin Properties.

Please refer to this link for more details. http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

Also please note, if you are using PhpMyAdmin sort of tool to control your mySQL server, then you need to put the Admin Properties according to that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link may help you :
http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Error-in-allocating-a-connection-Cause-null-td3358722.html

If your mysql tables have field names that have spaces in them, it will cause this problem.